Appropriate name of Lagrange's mean value theorem
I was studying mathematical analysis when a question came to my mind.
Almost every freshman studying calculus knowns about Lagrange's mean value theorem, which I therefore feel authorised not to recall. My problem with it does not lie in its statement or proofs, but rather in its name. Let me explain the source of confusion.
I was taught to call value of a function f at an argument x the object f(x). I was also taught to call average speed the ratio between a space variation and the corresponding time-interval length.
In this view, the assertion of Lagrange's theorem sounds quite strange: "mean value" almost surely refers to the amount which the theorem states is a value of the derivative function; but it is not a "mean value" of f according to the previous definition, for the same reasons the average speed is not called an "average space". It had better be called something like ""mean derivative"", just like one distinguishes average speed (corresponding to the latter) and instantaneous speed (corresponding to the derivative itself), but I don't know anything about this possibility.
Does anyone have a clearer view on this?

"One of the miseries of life is that everybody names things a little bit wrong, and so it makes everything a little harder to understand." -- Feynman

Variety is the spice of life. Its name in no way makes this result harder to understand.

I mean, you have a point

I think that you yourself have come very close to understanding Lagrange. For example, I would formulate it as follows: for any average speed there is an instantaneous speed equal to it on the same interval.

@zkutch I am aware of this interpretation and it obviously makes sense. For that exact reason the name "mean value theorem" seems to me pretty unclear: if you replace "speed" with "value of f", you get the "instantaneous value" which is not the derivative but rather the value of f itself, and a dual problem occurs if you replace "speed" with " value of f' ".

Speed instantaneous is value of $f'$ not $f$, which is coordinate. Simple speed always is same with average speed i.e. mean speed, which is secant.

@JohnZorich Thank you for your suggestion.

@zkutch It appears that mean value refers to f′. Formally it’s all right, still it seems odd to call ‘mean value theorem’ a statement about the mean value not of f but of f’. I guess it is done this way because Lagrange’s theorem is often introduced prior to primitives.
